# Fire makes whole scene pixelated

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I've been working on my own Pokémon animated movie for a month now. Everything works great except for the elements. I'm going to be using fire a lot in my movie, but whenever I render a scene with fire in it, the render turns out like the following. Any idea why this happens? I noticed that when I change the smoke domain from volume to any of the other options, that the pixelated area goes away, but then there is no fire and it only shows the UV sphere that is my emitter. There has been no help on any other help forums and I'm dying to finish my project; this is my only setback.

Comment: Can you upload a blend that shows this problem?

Comment: still a little new, how do I do that?

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: sorry one moment

Comment: Whatever you changed just turned everything purple . . .